# How to transfer multiple databases by sql-sync?

Tags: drush

I've created proper aliases and successfully pulled files/database from live to dev server by:

```
drush sql-sync @live @dev
```

But I noticed my secondary database (defined also in `settings.php` and in alias file) has not been populated when syncing. I have `default` database and one additional database for some special operations which I use.

There was no any error message after sync, so I presume `drush` did not try to copy that database.

Is there any additional procedure I must follow when doing sync of 2 databases, or this was presumed to be automatic?

If there is no out-of-the-box answer, or I should show my config files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drush sql-sync will only copy one database per run; if you have multiple databases to copy, you must run sql-sync multiple times.  Use --source-database=other and --target-database=other to specify some other database.  Use --source-target=mirror and --target-target=mirror if you want to copy a secondary mirror of your Drupal database (not your use-case).

Rename 'other' and 'mirror' to match the appropriate key of your database record.  See figure below.

```
Array
(
    [default] => Array
        (
            [default] => Array
                (
                    [driver] => mysql
                    [username] => www-data
                    [host] => localhost
                    [database] => drupaldb
                )
            [mirror] => Array
                (
                    [driver] => mysql
                    [username] => www-data
                    [host] => localhost
                    [database] => mirrordrupaldb
                )

        )
    [other] => Array
        (
            [default] => Array
                (
                    [driver] => mysql
                    [username] => www-data
                    [host] => localhost
                    [database] => otherdb
                )

        )

)
```

**Update from NenadP:**

It seems that you need to add `--strict=0` when using Drush 5 to work around a bug in the sql-sync command definition.  This has been fixed in Drush 8.6-6.x.

Comment: Tnx Greg, i hoped it is something that easy ;) asked same on drupal.org but one here gets a shiny medals. BTW your guidances spawned across the web are very helpfull.

Comment: I answer questions in the Drush issue queue as well, although now that you mention it, there was a day recently where I saw five support requests all pop up at the same time, and didn't have time to answer them. You can always bump d.o issues that don't get answers after a while, if they don't get any play the first time. I tend to think that Stack Exchange is a better place to ask support questions, though, as more people seem to see the questions here.  In any event, a kind word of thanks is an even better reward than a shiny medal, so thanks for the thanks!

Comment: Yes, I also deem highly Drupal StackExchange, I get answers much faster comparing to opening issue on Drupal.org. Somehow I ended up posting it here and there. It would be good if they can "integrate" it in some way. Also, giving answers here is so much rewarding, and I reckognize people better here than on drupal.org. It might be because of icons, reputation and all that stuff. :D

Comment: btw tnx for explaining mirror db as bonus :)

Comment: Greg, for further reading, I think you should add --strict=0 to answer, i got error without that option, explained elswhere :) . Maybe that is just me though

Comment: I don't think that --strict=0 is required on Drush 8.x-6.x.  Thanks for the tip about this Drush 5 bug, though.

Comment: It is drush 5.8 (one i got on my dev box machine when doing pear channel-discover pear.drush.org, pear install drush/drush) (sopose it is last stable ?)

Comment: Sad but true--there are bugs in the latest stable. All Drush maintainers use HEAD of 8.x-6.x on a day-to-day basis. An effort is made to backport bug fixes from 8.x-6.x to 7.x-5.x, but not all make it, and new stable releases are made only periodically. Hint: 7.x-5-x dev == latest stable plus backported bug fixes from 8.x-6.x, so its usually safe to use.

Comment: Apart from this, I am happy to have Drush - without Drush   Drupal is useless ;)